# End to end type safety of JSON between C# and typescript

Tags: c#, .net, json, typescript, static-typing

Both Typescript and C# supports type safe access to the members of an object checked at “compile” type, and json is used to transport “data transfer objects”  between web application back ends and their front end.

I would expect here to be tooling that could generate typescript “wrapper classes” from the C# classes that defined the JSON messages – yet I have never heard about such tooling being used.
It may be that not being an active TypeScript developer I have missed something in the TypeScript toolset for doing this, or that one of the “standard” JSON toolkits for .net already does it.   Or I could just be asking a very daft question…..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TypeLITE](http://type.litesolutions.net/) will convert C# classes into TypeScript interfaces:

```
public class Address {
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Becomes:

```
interface Address {
    Street: string;
}

interface Person {
    Name: string;
    Addresses: Address[];
}
```

This would keep your TypeScript honest when consuming a C# API.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a way to generate TypeScript "end points" that completely define the "JSON API" that the C# cope exposes?   (And a nice development/build "pipeline" to use it.)

Comment: I have a question about this though.  Once that typescript is compiled into Javascript, how can you force it to be safe?  I was writing an Angular2 app and was able to have a C# api return data in a different form than the interface I used in the Typescript, and I didn't get any sort of type error

Comment: @AlexKibler - TypeScript provides compile-time checking, not runtime checking (although there are derivatives that add runtime checking, such as TS*: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2014/07/what-is-ts-and-how-is-it-safer-typescript/)

Comment: @IanRingrose I don't have a complete story for you there - there are so many options and it depends on what your workflow is like at the moment. From the wealth of task runners out there, almost all could automate this.

Answer (score 0):

[Reinforced.Typing](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings) looks like it is an option and it seems to generate TypeScript code to call the webservice as well as the interfaces/objects to describe the returned data.

> Simply, this thing converts your .NET assemblies to TypeScript code.
>   It integrates to VisualStudio build process.

I think it is used less then TypeLITE, both are open source so can be expanded to match the needs of a given project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Reinforced.Typings](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings) and particularly [this sample](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/releases/download/v1.3.0/Samples.zip). There it is shown how to convert your MVC application controllers to AngularJS services returning `ng.IPromise<>` of your models and ensure type safety on build-time.